# C# Access Class members that implements an interface

Tags: c#, interface

This may be simple but I am new to Interfaces but after reading and watching some tutorials I learned how powerful they are so I trying to learn how to use them. So here is my question:

I have an Interface IDocument and a class PurchaseRequest that implements this interface (IDocument)

The class has 2 variables and 1 method, problem is that I can't access those else where.

This is the Iterface:

```
public interface IDocument
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the class that implements the IDocument interface:

```
public class PurchaseRequest: IDocument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int docNumber { get; set; }
    public int docRevision { get; set; }
    
    public void GenerateId()
    {
    }

}
```

And this is the main method where I am trying to access the class members but its not shown in the intelisense and is giving me error lines under the code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IDocument pr = new PurchaseRequest();
    // I can access this
    pr.Id = 0;
    // but I can't access those members
    /*
    pr.docNumber = 1;
    pr.docRevision = 0;
    pr.GenerateId();
    */

    Console.WriteLine("Press ANY key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: In a statically typed language like C#, you must always keep in mind the distinction between what an object _is_ (in this case, a `PurchaseRequest`), and how the code is currently viewing the object (in this case, it's viewing it as an `IDocument` interface object, because that's how you declared the variable `pr` that is referencing the object). If you want access to the `PurchaseRequest` members, then your variable has to be that type (i.e. either exactly `PurchaseRequest`, or some type that inherits `PurchaseRequest`). See duplicate for details.

Comment: I have type cast the 3 lines using `((PurchaseRequest)pr)` is this right ?

Comment: That would work, but it's better to just make the variable declaration `PurchaseRequest pr = new PurchaseRequest()`. Interfaces are useful, but that doesn't mean they should always be used. Only use the interface type when the code using the object _only needs the members of the interface_. It is good to restrict the code to interfaces; this helps ensure against unnecessary coupling between areas of the code. But if the code really needs access to the class members, then it should be given a variable that has the correct type. Casting each time you want to access a member is pointless.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for the reply, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When You cast class instance to another type (implemented interface, or inherited class) it hides all methods, fields and properties not specified inside that another type.